# RSS feed concatenator

Tags: linux, web-apps, rss

I have a bunch of RSS feeds that feed into a torrent client that runs on a somewhat unreliable machine. Rebuilding the feeds is a pain when it does go down. I have a more reliable machine that isn't really suitable for running torrents on that I can run arbitrary software on, so I'd like to use it to pick up the feeds periodically, and to combine them to make a single new feed that I can maintain, and feed into whichever torrent client happens to be running now.

Requirements:

- I need this to run on a modern version of Fedora or Ubuntu.
- Ideally I'd just want a line separated list of RSS feeds as an input. Anything else might be too fancy.
- I have a web server which can proxy available so its acceptable if i can just dump the output to an arbitrary folder, or if this is a standalone application on its own port.
- I don't particularly care about someone *reading* the file, so a simple, unauthenticated RSS feed output's fine.
- I'd like to maintain the format of each input entry of an RSS feed as is. Output should be a single RSS feed. I don't need any filtering or such. Many RSS feeds come in, one borged RSS feed comes out.
- I'm fairly language agnostic, but anything exotic may need instructions to install somewhere.
- if for some reason this needs a database, I have mysql and postgres available.
- cron is fine, if this is something that I need to set to run, say every hour or so.